# mocha.globals is "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, mocha.js

When trying to use [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) ([version 1.3.2](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/tags)) in the browser, along the lines of [the given example](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/example/tests.html), I get the following exception when trying to specify acceptable globals in [the expected way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11166354/19212) (i.e. with something like `mocha.globals(['amplify', '_'])`):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function Mocha(options) {
  options = options || {};
  this.files = [];
  this.options = options;
  this.grep(options.grep);
  this.suite = new exports.Suite('', new exports.Context);
  this.ui(options.ui);
  this.reporter(options.reporter);
  if (options.timeout) this.suite.timeout(options.timeout);
} has no method 'globals'
```

This is exhibited in Chrome 21.0.1180.

One may reproduce this by going to the [given example link](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/example/tests.html), and in the browser console run `mocha.globals(['123'])`.

I would expect `mocha.globals` to work as the linked example suggests, or there to be some documentation about an alternative, but I have found none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [issue #42](https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/442) on visionmedia/mocha GitHub. The solution is, in Coffeescript:

```
mocha.setup
  ui: 'bdd'
  globals: [ 'jade' ]
```

Comment: To follow up, the solution in js is:  mocha.setup({ ui: 'bdd', globals: ['jade'] })